# C saving game state, reducing passed variables

Tags: c

I've been wondering if there's a way to do a function that saves game state but in transparent way. It's not a question about actual saving (I know how to save to file etc), it's about writing it in a clear, simple and understandable way.

So far I've came to three ideas (remember, I wish it could be a function or some easy thing like `savegame()`), none is perfect:

1. Put every variable I want to save into a struct like:

```
struct state{
    int hp;
    pos position;
    int x;
    int y;
    ...
};
...
if(savegame==1) {
    state game;
    game.hp=hp;
    game.position=position;
    game.x=x;
    game.y=y;
    ...
    savegame(game);
}
```

as you can see, it's not looking any good, it takes so many lines to do just a saving: what if I would like to save like 40 variables? What if I want to do saving in like 5-6 places in a code?

2. Make my function long as snake (this gives a problem with loading it back, so for example I also put a `loadgame` func):

```
void savegame(int hp, pos position, int x, int y,...) // too long
{ ... }
void loadgame(int &hp, pos &position, int &x, int &y,...) // too long
{ ... }
...
int main()
{
    ...
    savegame(hp, pos, x, y, ...) // too long
    ...
    loadgame(hp, pos, x, y, ...) // too long
}
```

again, if it would have 40 variables inside(and i also would like to call savegame or loadgame like 5-6 times), it would take like 4 lines of code each(i just skip an idea to put it in 1 line)

3. Start my program with struct containing game state, and make all calculations, actually all game on that struct

```
struct gamestate{
    int hp;
    pos position;
    int x;
    int y;
}
...
int main()
{
    struct gamestate s;
    s.x++;
    ...
}
```

but this leads to a problem where everytime I make calculations I have to add this '`s`' at beggining.

**Conclusion:**

My idea was to maybe change second option just to reduce every call of `savegame(...)`; to simple `savegame();`, is there a way to do it? Without `define`?

Comment: Those are your sensible options.

Comment: If you are storing the game in a file you can `fread()` and `fwrite()` the `struct` directly.

Comment: You could also put all the game state variables into a section and save and load the entire section. This is non-standard and *will* screw up (especially when you recompile your program and the variables are in a different order). For the adventurous only.

Comment: So, to load game fread() would be enough, but anyway, unless i use option no. 3, i would have to do something like

Comment: struct mystruct=loadgame();
x=mystruct.x; etc.

Comment: it would reduce the inside of both functions, but anyway i would have to make the 'transporting' of variables if you know what i mean. I would appreciate if someone would post most 'common' option used by advanced programmers, and if you maybe know, idea that's behind choosing this particular one! :)

Comment: Yeah, of course, if you need to do calculations you need to access the members of the `struct`, if you are concerned about the number of parameters, divide it into small `struct`s and pass those `struct`s as parameters

Comment: Okay, so it's basically an option no. 3, thank you! - an information that there is no universal best option that i do not know is also a great information!

Comment: I have also came to an idea if i can use goto (tbh i have never used it) to some code outside of int main, to execute it and then after this code there will be something like 'goback', because i have been wondering if there's any way to put a code in some transparent place that will actually be in int main(so, i will have access to every single variable),

Comment: Why save the game on every move? Is your game crashing so often? Why not an Autosave every 100 moves or so? And upon exit by the user, also save it.

Comment: In C++ you could use reference variables, e.g. `int &x = game.x`. When you modify `x` in a calculation like `x++` you actually modify the value of `game.x`. With this you can avoid copying `x` back to the structure.

Comment: Use a compound `struct`, i.e. one containing several other structs, that at any one time contain all of the values representing states in your program.  This is very easily passed via a function(s) with very few arguments (prototyped eg. as `char *GetState(state *in, const char *filespec);` and `char *SetState(state *out, const char *filespec);` ) which in turn would write or read the contents of the struct into/out of a binary buffer.  I have used this method to store and retrieve multiple sets of state data within files, and I think it would work for your problem too.

Comment: One way I've been thinking about doing this sort of thing: wrap declarations with a blank `#define`, for example: `savevar(int x = 0;)` -> `int x = 0;`, but then write a python script or something to run through the file and detect all the vars I want to save.  Then somehow generate code to write all those values into a `struct`.  I already do something similar by parsing my entire codebase and generating meta type information using libclang from python, but I haven't tried it for saving state yet, so there might be some unforeseen difficulties...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a dynamic way to do something similar to what you describe in your 1st option, i.e. track a game state using pointer to struct but that also stores and recovers that data to and from a binary file...

The following .c and .h files illustrate the idea that you can use a compound struct, i.e. one containing several other structs, that at any one time contain all of the values representing states in your program. This is very easily passed via a function(s) with very few arguments (prototyped eg. as char *GetState(state *in, const char *filespec); and char *SetState(state *out, const char *filespec); ) which in turn would write or read the contents of the struct into/out of a binary buffer. I have used this method to store and retrieve multiple sets of state data within files.

Note, the structs have random fields that of course you will modify as needed, but the idea is that you can pass a single pointer value that points to all the state data, in every function where state date is updated, or needs to be stored.

so_SaveGameState.c

```
    #include <so_SaveGameState.h>

    unsigned char *pByteA;

    GAME_STATE game = {{{"jim", "C:\\ico1.ico", {10, 120, 3}}, {"joe", "C:\\ico2.ico", {80, 10, -5}},{"larry", "C:\\ico3.ico", {15, -45, -45}},{"sue", "C:\\ico4.ico", {-100, -45, 45}}}, ENVR_3}; 
    GAME_STATE *pGame = NULL;

    int main(void)
    {
        pGame = &game;//point to populated memory


        printf("Player 3 position\nx = %d\ny = %d\nz = %d\n", game.plyr[2].pos.x, game.plyr[2].pos.y, game.plyr[2].pos.z);
        //example function that changes game state
        UpdatePlayerPosition(&pGame, 2);
        printf("Player 3 position\nx = %d\ny = %d\nz = %d\n", game.plyr[2].pos.x, game.plyr[2].pos.y, game.plyr[2].pos.z);
        UpdatePlayerPosition(&pGame, 2);
        printf("Player 3 position\nx = %d\ny = %d\nz = %d\n", game.plyr[2].pos.x, game.plyr[2].pos.y, game.plyr[2].pos.z);
        UpdatePlayerPosition(&pGame, 2);
        printf("Player 3 position\nx = %d\ny = %d\nz = %d\n", game.plyr[2].pos.x, game.plyr[2].pos.y, game.plyr[2].pos.z);
        //prepare an instance of game state for storeing
        (const GAME_STATE *)pByteA = &game;
        int len1 = sizeof(game);
        BOOL status = storeState("C:\\tempextract\\binFileStruct.bin", pByteA, len1);

        //recover a stored state
        unsigned char *buf = recoverState("C:\\tempextract\\binFileStruct.bin");
        GAME_STATE *game_2 = (GAME_STATE *)buf;

        free(game_2);
        return 0;
    }

    unsigned char * recoverState(const char *filespec)
    {
       size_t sz = 0;
       int n = 0;
       unsigned char *binBuf = NULL;
        FILE *fp = fopen(filespec, "rb");
        if(fp)
        {
            fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
            sz = ftell(fp);
            fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);
            rewind(fp);

             binBuf = calloc(sz, sizeof(*binBuf));
            n = fread(binBuf, sizeof(unsigned char), sz, fp);
            fclose(fp);
        }
        if(n == sz)
        {
            return binBuf;
        }
        else
        {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    int storeState(const char *filespec, const unsigned char *buf, size_t sz)
    {
        int count = 0;
        FILE *fp = fopen(filespec, "wb");
        if(fp)
        {
            count = fwrite(buf, sizeof(unsigned char), sz, fp);
            fclose(fp);
        }
        return (count == sz) ? 1 : 0;
    }

    void UpdatePlayerPosition(GAME_STATE **game, int player)
    {
        static int x=0, y=0, z=0;

        static BOOL toggle = TRUE;

        toggle = (toggle == 1) ? -1 : 1;

        srand(clock());
        //using fake assignment here
        //i.e. you would have other criteria to set actual position
        x += toggle * rand()%300;
        y += toggle * rand()%300;
        z += toggle * rand()%300;

        (*game)->plyr[player].pos.x = x;
        (*game)->plyr[player].pos.y = y;
        (*game)->plyr[player].pos.y = z;
    }
```

so_StoreGameState.h

```
    typedef enum {//environment
        ENVR_1,  //bad weather
        ENVR_2,  //hill
        ENVR_3,  //pit
        ENVR_4,  //angry birds
        ENVR_5,  //enemy guard
        MAX_OBST
    }ENVR_TYPE;

    typedef struct {
        int x;
        int y;
        int z;
    }POS;

    typedef struct {
        ENVR_TYPE envir;
        //...
    }ENVIR;

    typedef struct {
        char name[20];
        char iconFile[260];
        POS pos;
        //...
    }PLAYER;

    typedef struct {
        PLAYER plyr[4];
        ENVIR env;
        //...
    }GAME_STATE;

    extern GAME_STATE game;

    unsigned char * recoverState(const char *filespec);
    int storeState(const char *filespec, const unsigned char *buf, size_t sz);
```